# Dynamically added element is forcing a reload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, eventhandler

I have a table that has a range of elements inside of it.
I have registered some event handlers and add these elements dynamically through injecting new html.

Everything works for the original elements, but when I add a new ( dynamically created element ) and trigger one of the newly created event handlers the page seems to force reload and I lose all of my data/content.

Here is a simplified version:

```
               <table id="asset-table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <tr class="asset-row">
                    <td align="center" style="padding-bottom: 32px;">
                      <form id="asset-title" class="asset-title">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Add Asset Title Here ..." id="title-input1" />
                        <input id="title-submit" class="submit" type="submit">
                      </form>

                      <p id="asset-title-replacement" style="text-align: center; display: none;"><strong></strong></p>
                   </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

            <button id="add-asset-button">Add Asset</button>
```

EventHandler

```
 // asset title load
  $('#asset-table').on("submit", '.asset-title',  function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("asset-title");
    let text = $(this).find('#title-input1').val();
    let td = $(this).children().first()
    td.find('.asset-title').hide();
    td.find('.asset-title').next('p').text(function () {
      return text
    }).css("font-weight", "Bold");
    td.find('.asset-title').next('p').show()
  });
```

To add the new element:

```
$('#add-asset-button').click(function () {
    console.log("adding asset");
    $('#asset-table').append("<tr class='asset-row'><td align='center' style='padding-bottom: 32px;'><form id='asset-title' class='asset-title'><input type='text' placeholder='Add Asset Title Here ...' id='title-input1' /><input id='title-submit' class='submit' type='submit'></form><p id='asset-title-replacement' style='text-align: center; display: none;'><strong></strong></p>/td></tr>")
  })
```

So when dynamically adding the element, everything goes as planned, it is once I interact with adding the new "title" and click submit that the page seems to reload and I lose any "state" and content previously handled.

The problem that I am having is that the eventHandler is bound to #asset-table, so when a dynamic element is created the "this" keyword is bound to the #asset-table element, so how can I specify which  that I am working with for that event??

Comment: shouldn't  '.assetTitle' be '#asset-title' when delegating the event, there is no element having the assetTitle class

Comment: plus when adding the next row, you have to attach the events again. it is better to create a Module that creates your elements and attaches the event listeners

Comment: the .on() method binds the events to the parent, so this is supposed to be handled.

Comment: @BenMuller true, but not if that parent is itself programmatically appended after the listener is attached.

Comment: I am not programatically appending a parent, I am appending a child...

Comment: @BenMuller You were appending the parent in the code you originally posted.

Answer (score 0):

You will have multiple forms with the same id as you have it now, though that's not the main problem. You're also listening to .assetTitle rather than .asset-title and your listener is wrong, which are the main problem. When you do:

```
 $('.asset-row').on("submit", '.assetTitle',  function (event) {
   ...
 })
```

jQuery will only listen for form submits within .asset-row that currently exist when the listener is attached. All of your subsequent .asset-rows with .asset-titles (not .assetTitle) that are created programmatically do not have listeners attached. Instead, you need to apply it to an element that is present when the listener is attached, and then listen to any programmatically-created elements within it, like this. Note that I've changed .assetTitle to .asset-title.

```
 $('#asset-table').on("submit", '.asset-title',  function (event) {
    ...
 })
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1t4g6uae/2/)

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. I do have it exactly as you say.

Comment: @BenMuller did you check the fiddle? The form does not submit and console logs "asset-title", meaning the event handler is properly attached. I'm not considering what happens after that since your question was about the forms unintentionally submitting.

Comment: yes, thanks that does solve part of the issue, if you can check my last edit I have added further clarification of the issue relating to "this"

Comment: @BenMuller mmk, done helping at this point. I've fixed the problem of your broken handler and I've applied the submitted text to the neighboring p (which I'm guessing is what you were trying to do, since there is no context in your original question). The key to learning on Stack Overflow is to ask a specific question (and not edit it with new info), get an answer, and build upon that answer for your own learning. No one can "guess" what you're trying to do beyond what's stated in your question. You wanted the event handler to prevent the form submitting. My answer does that and more.

Comment: @BenMuller $(this) is not bound to #asset-table in your handler, by the way, which is obvious in the fiddle. Good luck.